# ui-router not replacing ui-view in index.html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui, state

I have set up a basic AngularJS app in VS and cannot get the ui-router functionality working. I have looked at videos, blogs, SO answers and as far as I can tell I am doing everything right, although, I am brand new to web development.

First, here is the solution structure:

[image]

and the code...

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body ng-app="app">
        <div ui-view></div>

        <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="app/app.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);
})();
```

app.states.js:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app')
        .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

            $stateProvider
                .state('home', {
                    url: '/',
                    templateUrl: 'templates/test.html',
                    controller: 'testCtrl',
                    controllerAs: 'vm'
                })
        });
})();
```

test.html:

```
<div>
    <p>TEST PAGE</p>
</div>
```

testCtrl.js:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app')
        .controller('testCtrl', testCtrl);

    testCtrl.$inject = ['$state'];

    function testCtrl($state) {
        var vm = this;
        var userAuthenticated = false;

        init();

        function init() {
            $state.go('home');
        };
    };
})();
```

Can anyone see anywhere I have made a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [a working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/pXA9WcJRWkLtY2xQrnYk?p=preview)

I would say, that I miss these lines in your index.html

```
...
<script src="app/app.states.js"></script>
<script src="templates/testCtrl.js"></script>
```

That will loade the crucial state definition, and related controller. Check it in [action here](http://plnkr.co/edit/pXA9WcJRWkLtY2xQrnYk?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks Radim! I made two changes, added the lines you mentioned, but changed `<script src="app/templates/testCtrl.js"></script>` and in `app.states.js` changed templateUrl to `templateUrl: 'app/templates/test.html',`. Can I ask, _why?_ do I need to add those two .js files to index.html? It seems "unclean". I thought this is taken care of by IIFE? I apologise, I am very new to web development. In other words, is there another way I can achieve the same thing without needing to add those two .js files into index.html?

Comment: not experienced with IIFE, but scripts must be loaded into page that is the point